# Having For loop inside an already called method in Java

Tags: java

This code snippet is working fine, I just want to, sort of, beautify it.

```
if (Utils.isValidString(comment)) {

    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(list.get(21));
    for (int j = 1 ; j < quantity; j ++) {
        requestSpecification = requestSpecification
            .queryParam("items(" + j + ").weight", list.get(13))
            .queryParam("items(" + j + ").length", list.get(15))
            .queryParam("items(" + j + ").width", list.get(17))
            .queryParam("items(" + j + ").height", list.get(19))
            .queryParam("items(" + j + ").quantity", list.get(21));
    }
}
```

inside queryParam method I want to have my for loop. the for lop can either be called from another class or somehow having that inside the method.
Is that possible in Java?

It is worth mentioning that Requestspecification is a class used for API testing. If that helps.

Comment: This sounds like XY problem. Instead of proposing a solution, why not tell us what the problem is?

Comment: The question would then be, How would you change this code for the sake of Abstraction. It is too exposed right now.

Comment: Sure, so one idea off the bad is have an object represent the `item` and have the class provide a constructor for weight, length, width, height, and quantity but also a constructor to parse this queryParam/requestSpecification.

Comment: Thanks for the idea you shared. Could you please write a class to a very basic format?

Comment: would suggest to increase the readability of your code avoid using list.get(21), Set these values in a POJO class and then set it to queryParam.For example create a Pojo class named Specification with properties weight,height,length,width and quantity.

Comment: This is the main reason I have posted my question. Technically it does not have any problem. I just want to enhance the readability

Comment: I will need to know more to post an answer. What is `list` type? What is `requestSpecification` type?

Comment: List type is String, containing weight, length, width, height and quantity value. RequestSpecification has it own type known as RequestSpecification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what really you are trying to achieve here but, based on your code what I understand it that you want to return some specification based on the quantity.
So, you can create a class Spec with attributes like `weight`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `quantity`.

A `HashMap<Integer, Spec>` can store your specifications where your key is the quantity and your value is the specification for that quantity

```
Map<Integer, Spec> specMap = new HashMap<>();


List<Spec> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

if (Utils.isValidString(comment)) {//not sure what comment is

    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(n);//n is the max number of items. Dont think u have to store that in list
 for(int i=0;i<quantity;i++){
  Spec spec =  specMap.get(i); //assuming data is already populated in this map and passed to this method
  if(spec!=null){
   outputList.add(spec);
  }
 }
return outputList;
```

}